# Calling a child-specific method after it has been added to the array as a parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

I have 2 classes: BankAccount and CheckingAccount. The CheckingAccount class inherits from the BankAccount class.

```
ArrayList<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankingAccount>();
bankAccounts.add( new CheckingAccount(200.00) );
bankAccounts.get(0).writeCheck(100.00);
```

So I add the checking account into an array of bank accounts (later I have saving accounts also to do polymorphing stuff with), but since `writeCheck(double amount)` is only a method of the CheckingAccount class, it gives me an error on the last line saying a BankAccount doesn't have that method. Is there a way to cast for only lines where I use checking account specific methods? Or is there some other parameter to the line creating the ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CheckingAccount ca = (CheckingAccount) bankAccounts.get(0);
ca.writeCheck(100.00);
```

In this above code, the object returned from `bankAccounts.get(0)` being referred by a BankAccount's reference is being casted explicitly to a reference of the child class.

Either this, or you should have this mthod `writeCheck(double a)` defined in your BankAccount class. During compile time, it is checked whether the method being called is defined in the reference variable's class or not. Since you have no `writeCheck(double)` method defined in the parent class, the compiler throws an error for the code you wrote.

Runtime polymorphism will determine whether the reference variable points to an object of the parent class or an object of a child class. The method's signature must be present in your Parent class (BankAccount) as well, unless you explicitly do the above typecasting.

Hope this solves your doubts

Answer (score 3):

```
((CheckingAccount)bankAccounts.get(0)).writeCheck(100.00);
```

Or in a type safe manner

```
if(bankAccounts.get(0) instanceof CheckingAccount) {
   ((CheckingAccount)bankAccounts.get(0)).writeCheck(100.00);
}
```